# Rotation tween stop and tween start on mouse down

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an object rotating on z axis. `onMouseDown` the rotation stops and `onMouseUp` the rotation resumes after 2 seconds.
Is there a way for the rotation to resume slowly (like ease in for css)?

The code for the rotation start and stop.

```
                if ( etaj1 !== undefined ) {
                    etaj1.rotation.z += delta * 0;
                    if(!isMouseDown){
                        etaj1.rotation.z += delta * 0.05 ;

                    }
                }
```

Also there is a `resetTimer` condition if a new click is made before the 2 seconds have passed.

```
            var timerHandle = setTimeout (wait , 2000);
            function resetTimer () {
                window.clearTimeout (timerHandle);
                timerHandle = setTimeout (wait , 2000);
            }

            function onMouseDown(){
                console.log("Mouse DOWN");
                isMouseDown = true;               
            }

            function onMouseUp(){                   
                window.clearTimeout (timerHandle);
                timerHandle = setTimeout (wait , 2000);                 
            }

            function wait (){
                resetTimer;
                console.log("Mouse UP");
                isMouseDown = false;
            }
```

the idea is to make a transition for `isMouseDown = false;` and another transition for `isMouseDown = true;`

Basically what i want to do is stop the rotation from the link below with a quart.out tween, wait 2 seconds and if no click resume rotation with a quart.in tween.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a three.js guy, however what you are asking is applicable in other areas as well. So I will put here a general solution. First the proof of concept:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/u4xwnLam/4/

I'll start declaring the globals I need, wrap them up as you want:

```
var rotation = 0;
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
var container = document.getElementById("container");
```

I need to demonstrate this without three.js so I need to have a container and something to rotate so you do not need `bar` and `container` in your case. Rotation in your case is your `etaj1.rotation.z`

We first need a function that will map 0-1 to 0-1 again, but not linearly. These are called interpolations, there are many ones, cosine, this, that, most widely used one is a stitched and transformed x^3 and gives a "slow in slow out" affect:

```
 function slowInSlowOut(t){
    if(2*t<<0){
        return 4*(t-1)*(t-1)*(t-1)+1;
    } else {
        return 4*t*t*t;
    }
}
```

We have to do something with this function so I will write another animate

```
function changeSpeed(obj,newSpeed){
    var oldSpeed = obj.__oldSpeed || 0;
    var startTime;
    newSpeed = newSpeed || 0;
    obj.__currentFrame && window.cancelAnimationFrame(obj.__currentFrame);//cancel a previous changeSpeed if fired twice
    obj.__currentFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    function anim(t){
        startTime = startTime || t;
        var elapsed = t - startTime,
            parametric = slowInSlowOut(elapsed/2000);
        if(parametric>=1){
            obj.__oldSpeed = newSpeed;
        } else {
            obj.__oldSpeed = newSpeed + (oldSpeed-newSpeed) * (1-parametric);
            obj.__currentFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        }
    }
}
```

You provide this function an object, and it will attach it a proprietary `__oldSpeed` property, the `newSpeed` parameter is measured in means of **degrees/17ms** (because I am using requestAnimationFrame and that will fire each ~17ms). So in your case the `obj` is your `etaj1`.

Within this function you can already update your `etaj1.rotation.z` if you want. But I will write a third function to fire continuously and listen to `__oldSpeed` property and take action based on that:

```
function animate(obj){
    rotation += (obj.__oldSpeed || 0);
    rotation = rotation % 360;
    obj.style.transform = "rotate("+rotation+"deg)";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate(obj)});
}
```

Again here, obj is your `etaj1` and rotation is `etaj1.rotation.z`. I am using DOM here, so I need to use the styles. You can adapt it to your case.

Animate won't fire, so we need to fire him:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate(bar)});
```

I'll add the eventListeners as you described:

```
container.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){changeSpeed(bar,0)},false);
container.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){changeSpeed(bar,12)},false);
```

Now we give it a starting speed:

```
changeSpeed(bar,12);
```

There you go. In case you wondered how to do it yourself, this might get you started. I guess people using other technology stacks can also adapt this to their case.

## PS:

Someone mentioned a delay, in that case modify the `changeSpeed` a bit:

```
function changeSpeed(obj,newSpeed,delay){
    delay = delay || 0;
    var oldSpeed = obj.__oldSpeed || 0;
    var startTime;
    newSpeed = newSpeed || 0;
    obj.__currentFrame && window.cancelAnimationFrame(obj.__currentFrame);
    obj.__currentFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    function anim(t){
        startTime = startTime || t;
        var elapsed = t - startTime;
    if(elapsed < delay) {
       return obj.__currentFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    }
        var parametric = slowInSlowOut((elapsed-delay)/2000);
        if(parametric>=1){
            obj.__oldSpeed = newSpeed;
        } else {
            obj.__oldSpeed = newSpeed + (oldSpeed-newSpeed) * (1-parametric);
            obj.__currentFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle that has a 2 second delay:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/u4xwnLam/10/

Comment: Thank you for the high level of explanation... i will give +1 just for that.
Not doing what is needed. your script lacks the 2 seconds of not rotating after the mousedown event. take a look at http://renaultespace.littleworkshop.fr/ and move the car... you will understand what i need. :)

Comment: try to stop this animation on mouse click, have a 2 seconds of rotation break and then resume rotation
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada

Comment: The delay is not a big deal at all, check the ps. I added a 2 seconds delay.

Comment: One more thing... you have to hold down the mouse button for the rotation to fully stop. if i want the rotation to stop without the long press i should use mouseclick?

Comment: wait... in my code there is a condition check to see if mouse is clicked again the counter of the delay is reseted.

Comment: In that case don't make it complicated. You do not need mouseup or click for that. Just use this handler: `container.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){clearTimeout(this.__timeout);changeSpeed(bar,0);this.__timeout=setTimeout(function(){changeSpeed(bar,12,100)},2000)},false);` See this https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/u4xwnLam/11/